# Подпапки в контроллерах codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Как сделать, чтобы можно было использовать подпапки в папке controller? Например, `controller/admin/main/`, а то работает только `controller/admin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу первого роутинг позволит сформировать URL соответствующим образом. А разместить контроллеры в подпапках не удастся. А по поводу второго для начала и обучения фреймворк очень годный. По быстродействию вряд ли какой другой с ним сравнится. По скорости разработки и использованию современных тенденций да не очень современный, но инструмент проверенный и выбрасывать не стоит, я думаю.

Answer (score 1):

1. Это называется роутингом и лежит в соответствующей секции документации - https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html | http://cidocs.ru/210/general/routing.html
2. Выкиньте codeigniter. Это мамонт прошлого века. Он уже умер, на нем просто нет смысла писать, за исключением любителей суицида через простреленное колено.